# Can I embed an axml into a xaml (Xamarin)?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin, and am setting up a `Xamarin Forms` app, and triggering  the device's camera after creating the intent and starting an activity for it.

Pretty much what Xamarin's recipe looks like, but I am using `Forms.Context` as the Activity object (in order to place all the hookings inside my content page, as opposed to having everything within `MainActivity.cs`, as in Xamarin's recipe).

It works, the camera is opened.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
_file = new File(_dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));
Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent, Bundle.Empty);
```

The thing is I want the same as the recipe's feature of putting the picture just taken into an `ImageView`.

The [recipe's code](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/) generates the UI (and everything else) within `MainActivity.cs`. I wanted to keep the view declared separately, in its `XAML` file.

As far as I understand, I need to be able to embed a `axml` android resource file into the `xaml`, because code in `MainActivity` is already Android-ported, and Android can reference views/controls only by their resource id (which are automatically generated after creating the `view/ui container` as an `axml` file under `Resources/layout` folder.

How do I complete this last step in order to have the Take a Picture sample working - coded outside the `MainActivity`?

**Screenshots**:

Here's how the Xamarin recipe puts the picture taken into the image viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are working with Xamarin Forms and want to take a picture and then display it with an `Image` - I suggest you use https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin which allows to let the user take a photo (or pick one from the phone). The result can be set as the `ImageSource` of an `Image`.

About the original question, whether you can embedd a native android element into xamarin Forms - you can check out https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/

Comment: Thanks, at this time I am not sure I want to add plugins, but looks like an alternative worth checking.

Comment: The code is open source, too. You could use it as a 'source of inspiration'. About the original question, whether you can embedd a native android element into xamarin Forms - you can check out https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/

Comment: The problem with xamarin's scenario is that the platform-specific control must be already be alive. I wanted to have a placeholder in the forms layout which the platform-specific code could access.

Comment: Can you post / link some code you already worked up? I don't fully understand what you want to do. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/#Android provides an example of how to dynamically add an android element into a Xamarin.Forms Layout. If you need some kind of 'TakePhotoService' which returns something you can use as an Xamarin.Forms ImageSource the Plugin / Code of the Plugin is your best bet

Comment: I am now following Grace's suggestions, it seems this is what I was looking for (I edited the question stating I am a new to Xamarin, so I am yes a bit confused with the flow and the way the question was formulated may not be clear...)

Comment: That was the direction i wanted to lead you aswell :) The mentioned plugin would save you a lot of work (setting it up already registeres the platform specific implementation) and you wouldn't have to create a CustomRenderer because the Plugin returns a Stream which you can use as an ImageSource for Xamarin.Forms Image. All the Plugin actually is, is a Nuget Package you install. It doesn't have a high impact on performance or anything. No reason not to use it ;) Good luck!

Comment: Am marking this as the answer for the mention to Media Plugin, the only way I managed to achieve a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to deal this is to use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access Android native feature, to be specific here, to call the native method of taking a picture and save the picture. If you just want take a picture and display it with Image, you can use `DependencyService` to implement this platform specific feature and design your layout in xaml, there is no need to embed axml in XAML.

If you want to embed the camera preview in Xaml, the suggested way is to use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) to render the interface using the native controls of target platform. It means, you don't need to create a axml in Android project to display camera preview, you can create a custom renderer (control/ view) in PCL, and implement this control in your Android project. There is official [doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/) and [demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/View/) which guides us to implement a view to display the camera preview.

Comment: Sounds like your answer is what I was looking for. Checking.

Comment: I have been trying for a long time, without success - how, after running the implementation picked by the Dependency Service, do I reach the OnActivityResult of the MainActivity (which is who implements the dependency) ? Why OnActivityResult will not be executed after StartActivity, StartActivityForResult... ?

Comment: @Veverke, by my side, `OnActivityResult` can be successfully fired.  The `OnActivityResult` will be fired and then the `OnResume` in PCL will also be fired.

Comment: I tried it lots of times yesterday, was very frustrated. If this works, I can understand the flow basics. I have no idea why this is not working, and thus I resorted to Media Plugin. But I would definitely prefer using a DepedencyService and nothing else. Will give it a try again today.

Comment: @Veverke, I tried a demo just now, I can successfully get bitmap in `OnResume` and `OnActivityResult`, but I have problem with setting this bitmap to image control in PCL, I googled a little, seems it has problem with `ImageSource.FromStream`, didn't look into this problem further.

Comment: @Veverke, to understand how to use `DependencyService`, you may refer to [Working with Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/), if you need my demo, I can share it.

Comment: Thanks for all the good will Grace, yes, I had trouble in converting an Android Bitmap into one of the sources from which I can populate the xamarin's image source property. But my problem is really not being able to hit OnActivityResult or OnResume (did not work with this one, perhaps this is my problem?). I will check and report again. Thanks. In case I make no further progress, will ask for your demo.

Comment: Grace, where is your OnActivityResult located ? Are you using the one from MainActivity ? This is what I am doing (tried not working within the main activity, but without success). Anyway, [here](https://gist.github.com/Veverke/655c361dd74ebf73deb9d4b2aa2b77f1)'s my gist for my scenario.

Comment: @Veverke, Yes, `OnActivityResult` is located in `MainActivity` and `OnResume` is located in App.xaml.cs of PCL, did you set permission in android project's manifest? I think this could be the real problem with your code.

Comment: Permissions ? Nope. First, I was referring to OnResume on MainActivity as well, so one problem here. Secondly, permissions ? Which permissions am I missing ? (The only permissions I added were CAMERA and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: OnResume within App.xaml.cs is not fired as well.

Comment: @Veverke, no clue why, but my demo fires OK by my side, you can have a try: [CameraDemo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/XamarinFormsCameraDemo), and as I said, I didn't finish the job of displaying the android bitmap in PCL, this demo is also just for android platform.

Comment: All right, will download your demo now and try it. Thanks

Comment: Your demo works indeed, and I noticed my Interface resided within the Android project instead the Forms one. Then it also worked, and now I wanted to make sure this was the problem... I deleted the one from Forms, but it still works. I also noticed my implementation had no intent and start activity in the first place, so of course I would never reach OnResult (have no idea how I missed that...). I must have chosen the wrong profession. Thank you, anyway.